# DateTime value not converted to specific format in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to convert the value "2018-05-18 09:57:00" to May 18 2018  9:57AM.
Below is my SQL and I have tried different methods but still showing the same result.

```
SELECT 
   b.BookingID ,
   (SELECT CONCAT(il.CarrierCode,'(', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),il.DeparDate,0)')')
FROM Booking b
LIMIT 1
```

But this is working when I pass `GETDATE()` and not working with my column. Please help me. I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2017.

Thank you

Comment: Which database do you use? tag your database

Comment: Updated the question. I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2017

Comment: What is the data type for `DeparDate` ? Also your query seems incomplete

Comment: `SQL Server` does not have `LIMIT` keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this formatting `CONVERT(varchar,[datefield],100)` to get the desired format of your `datetime` field. if the data type of your field is `string`, cast it to `datetime` so this `sql` date formatting will work.

```
SELECT b.BookingID ,(SELECT CONCAT(il.CarrierCode,'(', convert(varchar,cast(il.DeparDate as datetime), 100)')')
FROM Booking b
```